# Speech utterance in Hebrew

Tags: xcode, speech, hebrew

I'm developing an application that talks in many different languages. However, for some reason it will not speak in Hebrew. I've tried using Hindi, Arabic and even Greek but none of them seem to work. I'm just wondering if there is a dialect that will read back Hebrew or if I'm going to have to wait for an update.

Code Snippet:

```
if ([secondName  isEqual: @"Hebrew"])
{
    utt.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"ar-SA"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're starting the `AVSpeechSynthesisVoice` with Saudi-Arabian Arabic, and not `he-HE` Hebrew.